# Simple question on how to display XML attribute on a specific code

Tags: php, xml

I am kinda new in XML but I can handle some things. Below there is a code that gets value from a HTML form and then displays some info from a XML file (see below). The code shows correctly all the info (TITLE, BAND, YEAR), but my question is how can I display also the id attribute of `<CD id="XXX">`. Thank you!

**the code**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("database.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('TITLE');

for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++)
{
//Process only element nodes
if ($x->item($i)->nodeType==1)
  {
  if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q)
    {
    $y=($x->item($i)->parentNode);
    }
  }
}

$cd=($y->childNodes);

for ($i=0;$i<$cd->length;$i++)
{
//Process only element nodes
if ($cd->item($i)->nodeType==1)
  {
  echo("<b>" . $cd->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
  echo($cd->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
  echo("<br />");
  }
}
?>
```

**XML**

```
<CATEGORIES>

<CD id="1">
<TITLE>NEVER MIND THE BOLLOCKS</TITLE>
<BAND>SEX PISTOLS</BAND>
<YEAR>1977</YEAR>  
</CD>

<CD id="2">    
<TITLE>NEVERMIND</TITLE>
<BAND>NIRVANA</BAND>
<YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
</CD>

</CATEGORIES>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it would be nicer to do this searching using XPath.  The query to find a `TITLE` element that have the content `foo` is `//TITLE[.="foo"]`.  You can then use [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) to get the attribute you want. So your code could look something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load("database.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$el = $xpath->query('//TITLE[.="' . $q . '"]');

if ($el->length) {
    $cd = $el->item(0)->parentNode;

    echo "<b>ID:</b> " . $cd->getAttribute('id');

    foreach ($cd->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeType == 1) {
            echo("<b>" . $node->nodeName . ":</b> ");
            echo($node->nodeValue);
            echo("<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user560411 If this (or another!) answer has answered your question, you can mark the question as answered by clicking on the empty tick symbol to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of dealing with XML is to use SimpleXML like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('database.xml');
foreach ($xml as $cd) {
    echo 'ID: ' . $cd['id'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Title: ' . $cd->TITLE . '<br>';
    echo 'Band: ' . $cd->BAND . '<br>';
    echo 'Year: ' . $cd->YEAR . '<br>';
}
```

See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I would like to stick with the above code and just display the id attribute..

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive a DomNode's attributes by calling $node->attributes().

For more information see this function's documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.domnode-attributes.php

Comment: Hi there, i tried to implement it but i can't add it right. I can't handle it right because it is a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOMElement::getAttribute() method, so in your example:

```
echo $cd->item($i)->getAttribute("id");
```

Refer to the API http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php